# How many ways are there to go from the point $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ using,right up and down moves that we don't pass a point more than once?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways are there to go from the point $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ using,right up and down moves that we don't pass a point more than once?

I tried using to calculate every case(depending on the down moves) then maybe the identity $\sum\limits_{r=0}^m n^r \binom{m}{r}=(n+1)^m$ will work.(because the answer in the book is $(n+1)^m$).But it didn't work.Any hints?

Comment: You might need to be a bit more specific about what you mean by "...right up and down..." If these moves are all possible then there are an infinite number of n or u shaped paths.

Comment: There's an error here methinks - for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, what stops me from going down $k$ steps, right $m$ steps, and up $k + n$ steps. This gives at least one path for every $k$, giving countably infinite paths (much larger than $(n+1)^m$.

Comment: Maybe you want us to stay in the rectangle defined by $(0,0), (m,0), (0,n), (m,n)$? In that case, the answer below is the correct one. Maybe you want paths of a set length? In that case, it might be possible to adapt the proof for the number of paths using only up or right moves.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the assumption that movement is only allowed in the grid formed by corner points $(0,0), (m, 0), (0, n), (m,n)$:

For each column, there are $n+1$ ways to pick where the horizontal movement occurs. After placing the horizontal movements for each column, there's only one way to connect them all (and these connections are done entirely in terms of up/down movements that do not revisit any position more than once).

Over all $m$ columns, that's $(n+1)^m$ paths in total, which matches the answer in your book.

Comment: As the question stands, there are an _infinite_ number of places to pick a crossover point.

Comment: @Arthur Normally for path problems like these, it's a grid bounded from $(0,0)$ to $(m,n)$ for positive integers $m,n$. But yes, the OP should probably mention this.

Comment: Normally, yes. But not necessarily. What if he instead of the rectangle were limited to paths of some specified length? Whatever limitation the original problem author intended, it got lost when transcribing it to this site, and you have no way of knowing what that limitation is until we get some form of confirmation.

Comment: @Arthur If that were the case, his book's answer would likely not be $(n+1)^m$.

Comment: True. But seing as there are _many_ ways to impose limitations on this problem, I don't think it's the only way. I do agree wholeheartedly with you that it is very probable that this is the actual limitation in the actual problem. But we _do not know_. In my opinion, you shouild begin your answer with a disclaimer.

Comment: @Arthur Good idea - disclaimer added